# Problem passing String[][] from Java to R using rJava

Tags: java, r, rjava

Is it possible to return from Java a String[][] to R using rJava?

I call the method

```
public String[][] readFromTable(String tableName, String security,
        String[] fields, String startTime, String endTime, boolean reverse)
```

from R with

```
   out <- .jcall(obj, "[[S", "readFromTable", tableName, security, .jarray(fields),
    start, end, reverse)
```

When I change the return type of the method to String[] everything works just fine, I
experimented with the parameters and I am pretty sure that the problem is the String[][].

Has anyone got an idea?

**EDIT 1:** 
Sorry, I forgot the error message:
Error in .jcall(obj, "[[S", "readFromTable", tableName, security, .jarray(fields),  : 
  method readFromTable with signature (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)[[S not found

**EDIT 2** 
I just figured out that it works if I return a Double[][]...so maybe there is a bug in
the String JNI implementation in the rJava package but that's hard to believe

Comment: I also tried it with [[Ljava/lang/String instead of [[S but that does not work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[Ljava/lang/String;

This will work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to play with the .jarray? It was an issue of my problems.

```
.jarray(fields, contents.class="Ljava/lang/String")
```